# Cypress: Getting Cypress detected that you invoked one or more cy commands in a custom command but returned a different value

Tags: cypress

While returning any single /set of values from a function (from command.js /Page object class) getting error as "Cypress detected that you invoked one or more cy commands in a custom command but returned a different value.". I have searched different options like 'Warp', '.then' but not have the luck.

Following are the details:

**My Command.js file:**

```
Cypress.Commands.add("getconstantvalue", () => {
    const todaysDateTime = Cypress.moment().format('MMMDDYYYYSS')
    cy.log(todaysDateTime)
    return todaysDateTime
})
```

and I want this 'todaysDateTime' in my driver/describe suit script:

```
describe('The Home Page', function() {
  it('successfully loads', function() { 
    var data = cy.getconstantvalue()
    cy.log(data)       
  })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. You just have to chain it to the command you are using.

Command.js File

```
Cypress.Commands.add("getconstantvalue", () => {
    const todaysDateTime = Cypress.moment().format('MMMDDYYYYSS')
    cy.log(todaysDateTime)
    return cy.wrap(todaysDateTime)
})
```

Test File

```
describe('The Home Page', function() {
    it('successfully loads', function() {
        cy.getconstantvalue().then(data => {
            cy.log(data);
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: Not have the luck, getting the same error as:  "Cypress detected that you invoked one or more cy commands in a custom command but returned a different value.
The custom command was:

  > cy.getconstantvalue()

The return value was:

  > Aug20202094

Because cy commands are asynchronous and are queued to be run later, it doesn't make sense to return anything else.

For convenience, you can also simply omit any return value or return undefined and Cypress will not error.
.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Now I am returning `cy.wrap(todaysDateTime)` instead of only todaysDateTime. can you try once now.

Comment: I Applied similar way to return a list of elements from a page object class function but getting one issue. I am going to raise separate question and link here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63504962/11755763 @alapan Das Could you plz look at this